# GCP VM is Inaccessible by SSH

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a GCP VM that is inaccessible.  I cant SSL to it.  I was able to get in last week but not today.  I tried stopping and starting it and that did not help.

Comment: If SSH was working and you made no changes AND the VM instance is small and has been running for a while, then you probably ran out of disk space. Connect to the serial console and review the startup logs for an error message. If a free space issue, resize the disk larger. Otherwise, edit your question and provide details.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide to troubleshooting common SSH errors which may help: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh